# Spring MVC resources not found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, resources

I know that there are many post about this, but I have 2 days testing all (or maybe the majority) the answer about my question and I continue with the same problem.
I'm trying to make a really simple webapp that have an index.jsp and navigate to a login.jsp
Both of them have some static resources (like css or png) that I have included under WebContent, so I have:

```
WebContetn
|
|-----------resources (some subdirectories inside)
|
|-----------WEB-INF
            |
            |-----pages
                  |
                  |-----index.jsp
                  |-----login
                        |
                        |-----login.jsp
```

When I start my app index.jsp is shown perfectly (including static resources) but when I navigate to login.jsp by clicking a buttom inside index.jsp, the resources arem't loaded.

I have sawn that the context root change when I navigate and I am sure that this is the problem but I'm not able to solve it.

Thanks.

This is my configuration:

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
        version="3.0">
  <display-name>testSpringMVC</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="main.java.es.testSpringMVC.**" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

springapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>        

</beans>
```

The Main controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping({ "/", "/index" })
    public String showHomePage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        return "index";
    }
}
```

The login controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginSIDController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login/loginSID")
    public String loginSID() {
        return "login/loginSID";
    }
}
```

And here the jsps.

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resources/imagenes/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="resources/estilos/estilosmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="cuerpo">

    <img src="resources/imagenes/logo.png">
    <br/>
    <div class="botonera">
        <a href="<c:url value='/login/loginSID'/>" class="boton" >SID</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

loginSID.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>SID Login</title>
<link href="resources/estilosSID/estilosLogin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%"  height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
      <table width="1000" height="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="resources/estilosSID/images/login.png">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form name="flogin" method="post" AUTOCOMPLETE="false"'>  
                <input type="submit" style="display:none">
                  <table width="322" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="42">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td width="280"><img src="resources/estilosSID/images/transparente.gif" width="3" height="30"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td><table width="85%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                          <td width="45%" class="tituloCampo"> Usuario:</td>
                          <td width="55%" class="celdaCampo"><input type="text" name="lf_user" size="15"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="tituloCampo"> Contrase&ntilde;a:</td>
                          <td class="celdaCampo"><input type="password" name="lf_pass" size="15"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          <td><div align="right">
                            <img src="resources/estilosSID/images/btnLogin.png" width="79" height="29" onclick="document.flogin.submit();"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  </form>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can You show us the respective controller method and the the portion of codes in `index.jsp` file used for calling `login.jsp` ?

Comment: yes, it's done. Sorry.

Comment: have you tried using JSTL url tag for those resources like images and css?

Comment: like <link href="<c:url value="resources/estilosSID/estilosLogin.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: I didn't tried it because as I said, index.jsp works fine and Im'm not using that tag. So if one works, why the other doesn't work?

Comment: Tried and doesn't work. Takes the url like: http://localhost:8080/testSpring/login/%3Cc:url%20value='resources/estilosSID/estilosLogin.css'%20/%3E

Comment: Have you included jstl in your jsp..?.because as per your url output..the tag is not resolved to expected url.

Comment: **** I forgot add <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> but I'm getting the 404. For some reason the URL is resolved like http://localhost:8080/testSpring/login/resources/estilosSID/estilosLogin.css when it should be http://localhost:8080/testSpring/resources/estilosSID/estilosLogin.css